# Exporting shp into a GPS

Tags: qgis, gps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert .shp into .gpx using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40731/how-to-convert-shp-into-gpx-using-qgis)

I'm trying to convert a shapefile with some random points into a gpx file, but I'm having some problems: when I upload the gpx file into my Garmin Etrex, the points doesn't have coordinates. Why?

ps: I'm working with the EPSG 3003, and I've regulated the Garmin too.

ps: I'm using QGIS 1.8 Lisboa on Mac OsX Mountain Lion. The main problem is that the GPS Tools is not working properly

Answer (score 3):

`Save as...` and selecting GPX format should work. Check `Surpress attribute creation` to avoid error messages.

GPX is only defined for EPSG:4326, that is WGS84 lat/lon.

You have to save your data in that CRS, regardless what you have set for **display** on your Etrex.

You can open the GPX file with any text editor to see if the coordinates are in there.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the schema of the GPX file, you can try the following:
1. Re-project your SHP to WGS84
2. Using Microsoft Excel, or another text editor which can read .dbf, extract the data as required by GPX.

What I mean is, if it's only the lat/lon, you only need to copy that out of the .dbf and into the GPX