# Trouble Converting from a shp. to gpx file and up loading to GPS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, gps, convert, gpx

Currently I have a series of random points within a shapefile that I would like to upload to my GPS. Every time I try to upload the points via "Save file" it come up with an error message (posted below).

- I have tried turning `Force_gpx_Track=Yes` and it still does not work.
- I have also tried unclicking the skip attribute creation and nothing works.

It worked one time and then come up with a select file class with waypoints, lines, and tracks so I clicked on waypoints and it ran the file.

Once I try to add the file to my GPS (Garmin GPSMAP 64) using GPS tools it only comes up with tracks under Upload to GPS any help would be great because it have reached a road block and need to have this inventory done.

[image]

**Error Message**

```
Export to vector file failed.
Error: creation of data source failed (OGR error:Failed to create GPX file Inventory_Points .gpx.
```

---

Still having trouble converting SHP to GPX, had it work once and never again. I created the name field (seen below) and copied the folder into my Garmin 64 via copy and past but it shows up blank. The one time it worked was with random points, now I am trying to get it to work with a grid

In the post above I checked skip attribute creation and forced GPX tracks with still no prevail. There is also no blanks at the end of the inventory_points

Was also wondering if I could use a program called basecamp or DNR_gps to export the file that way, if so could someone post the directions?
[image]

Comment: I used to use EasyGPS for uploading SHP data to my GPS devices: http://www.easygps.com/ (free).  See if you can get it done that way.

Comment: need a [name] field there are other related posts on GIS-SE http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76271/qgis-convert-vector-points-to-gps-waypoints-and-route

Comment: Is there a blank at the end of Inventory_Points? Try Browsing to an output folder. Maybe you have no write permission on the default target (the program folder).

Comment: Still having trouble converting SHP to GPX, had it work once and ever again. I created the name field (seen below) and copied the folder into my Garmanin 64 via copy and past but it shows up blank. The one time it worked was with random points, now I am trying to get it to work with a grid

In the post above I checked skip attribute creation and forced gpx tracks with still no prevail. There is also no blanks at the end of the inventory_points

Was also wondering if I could use a program called basecamp or DNR_gps to export the file that way, if so could someone post the directions?

Comment: Try with a name field called `name`. And make sure the extent is within +/-180/90°.

Answer (score 1):

Although it doesn't solve the problem with QGIS, you can, as mentioned in a comment, use DNR Garmin (DNR GPS) to convert your ESRI shapefile to GPX. This is what I do most of the time.

It is very simple. Just open the shapefile with the program, select the Id field if prompted, then export (or save as) to the desired format (in your case, GPX).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have access to ArcGIS, but they have a tool to convert features to a GPX:

https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=067d6ab392b24497b8466eb8447ea7eb

Comment: The question is about QGIS so an answer about ArcGIS isn't really useful.  Furthermore a link only answer isn't in keeping with the standard expected.  You could salvage this by documenting the process of using the ArcGIS tool in your answer, which would help those coming to this question who do have ArcGIS.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, below are the steps I followed.

1. Right-click on the shapefile in Qgis,
2. Select export and then "save feature as" GPX.

A new window of "save feature as" will open, provide the path where you want the file to be saved in "filename" then in the "geometry" tab select the shape of your file in " GPX_USE_Extension" select yes this will allow name, id and other feature that you want gpx file to have, now click okay.

Your file will be saved in gpx format in the desired location.

**Note: you need to put the name field otherwise even though your file might be saved in the GPS but it will still be blank.**