# How to export and import gps points from Garmin 62S and QGIS

Tags: qgis, gps, gpx

I'm pretty new to using QGIS and I'm curious about how to import and export GPS points created in QGIS. I have QGIS 2.0.1 Dufour on Windows XP and a Garmin 62s. Any suggested walk throughs would be great.

Comment: Salut, J'ai formaté mon Gps garmin 62sc avec caméra sans le savoir. Quand j'ai envie d'enregistrer les coordonnées géographiques on me dit Database error. Veuillez m'aider pour réparer ça

Comment: Hello, It looks like you are posting a new question rather than an answer, so this answer is likely to be deleted.  As a new user please take [the tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com) to learn about the Q&A format of this site, and then post a new question with as much details as possible.

Answer (score 4):

The Garmin GPSMap 62 series should mount like a flash drive when you plug it into a USB port. There are a number of directories on the drive, and to view points and lines you copy GPX files into one of the directories.

1. Export your points from QGIS as a GPX file:

   - 'Save As', selecting GPX as the export format, and in the 'Data source' field you put `GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=yes`.
   - See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40731/how-to-convert-shp-into-gpx-using-qgis/40733#40733) for more information.
2. Copy the resulting GPX file into the `E:\Garmin\GPX` folder (substitute E for whatever drive letter Windows assigns).

Tips:

- Waypoint names will be taken from a `name` field, if available; make sure your QGIS vector file has this field (text, 12 characters).
- You could use Garmin Mapsource (came on the CD with the GPS) to do the same job, but why let a proprietary system manage your data for you?

Answer (score 0):

Simbamangu's instructions didn't work for me right away, at least not with GPSmap64, because my points in QGIS were in a projected coordinate system. So, when you save as, choose WGS84 from the geographic coordinate systems as the coordinate system for the exported GPX file. You can also choose gpxx as a namespace for the GPX file instead of the default OGR, as that's what Garmin uses, but that doesn't necessarily matter (I didn't really test it).