# How to keep the ids of way points of a shapefile when I convert it to a GPX file in QGIS?

Tags: shapefile, gpx

I tried to convert a shapefile to a GPX file in QGIS, and I do not know how to keep the ids (attributes). What is the solution?

Comment: you should try to elaborate on your question, and include details such as what software you are using, what type of gps device you are using, and what method of transferring the data you have attempted so far

Comment: Please, see Andre Joost's answer at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40731/how-to-convert-shp-into-gpx-using-qgis

Answer (score 3):

Waypoints in GPX can have a 'name' (appears in the xml between 'name' tags). [Specification for relevant part of the xml is here](http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/#type_wptType).

They don't have an 'id'.

The background to this is that for standard GIS data you can give data fields any name you choose, but GPX is very specific about the data attributes.

I don't do this for waypoints, but I'm assuming the same system will work as I use for tracks... which is that I ensure before export that my data table has only one field, called 'name'. This is exported into the GPX file in the appropriate way.

There are more complex things you can do with GPX files using [the extension tag](http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/#type_extensionsType) but I tend to think that's asking for trouble (the point about GPX being it's standardisation and suitability for a very specific purpose).