# Google maps to gpx

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, gpx

I have taravel map created in google maps. Now I need to save way points in GPX format to make them available for my GPS Osmand application. How to solve this problem?

Comment: is this map in fusion tables? or json?

Comment: This might help: http://labs.coruscantconsulting.co.uk/garmin/gpxgmap/convert.php

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of approaches you could take, including:

- Save your map as a KML file, open that file in [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/), and [save as
  gpx](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40731/how-to-convert-shp-into-gpx-using-qgis).
- Use an online converter like [GPS Visualizer](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/convert_input). You can paste your
  map's URL directly into the tool as presented in [this tutorial](http://bedsforcyclists.co.uk/articles/2014/04/13/how-to-plan-a-route-in-google-maps-and-export-it-to-gpx-your-phone/). Other possible converters include [GMapToGPX](http://www.elsewhere.org/journal/gmaptogpx/), [TakeItWithMe](http://www.takitwithme.com/), and several others available via search.

Comment: But how to save to KML file using google maps. I can't find  menu command like that. I'm working on China map

Comment: @vico Does this help: https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3109452?hl=en