# Using 'ogr2ogr' algorithm in QGIS to transform SHP to GPX

Tags: qgis, ogr, gpx

So I am trying to convert a LineString shapefile into GPX using the 'gdalogr:ogr2ogr' algorithm in a QGIS python plugin.

The problem is that I alway get routes instead of tracks, even if I specify the option 'FORCE_GPX_TRACK=YES'. The input is actually a LineString, not a MultiLineString (by default, LineString are created into the route layer). But the 'FORCE_GPX_TRACK' option is supposed to create it as a track...

Here is the code:

```
processing.runalg("gdalogr:ogr2ogr",inputf,16,'FORCE_GPX_TRACK=YES',self.GUIControl.output_path + os.sep + "GPX" + os.sep + filename)
```

EDIT:

Maybe I should mention that I am trying this on QGIS 2.4 on Linux (debian)

I tried 'gdalogr:convertformat' on QGIS 2.12 on Windows and it wrote the GPX file with the correct geometries, as tracks. But, there are no attributes though. Maybe I should use '-select field_list' option after -lco ?

I will try it tommorrow, because i'm on my windows machine right now. I just wanted to post an update of my problem to let you know i'm still alive :P

Comment: For the attributes, you need `-dsco GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=YES`. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40731/how-to-convert-shp-into-gpx-using-qgis

Comment: See AndreJ's answer. It didn't work in QGIS 2.4, but it does in 2.8 (both in linux).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ogr2ogr you have dataset creation options, and layer creation options. According to http://www.gdal.org/drv_gpx.html, FORCE_GPX_TRACK=YES is a **LAYER** creation option.

So you have to add `-lco "FORCE_GPX_TRACK=YES"` to get the tracks instead of routes.

This works for the command line version just the same.

Make sure the data is in EPSG:4326.

---

The above runs fine in the processing toolbox. You can look inside the logfile under `C:\Users\<username>\.qgis2\processing\processing.log` to see the executed command:

`08:47:59|processing.runalg("gdalogr:convertformat","<input-shapefile>",16,"-lco FORCE_GPX_TRACK=YES","<output-gpxfile")`

So I suggest to use `gdalogr:convertformat` instead of `gdalogr:ogr2ogr`. See http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/ogr_conversion.html#convert-format for the documentation, or `processing.alghelp("gdalogr:convertformat")`.

Comment: I tried to add "-lco" before, but I still get routes instead of tracks:  


processing.runalg("gdalogr:ogr2ogr", inputf[0], 16, "-lco FORCE_GPX_TRACK=YES", self.GUIControl.output_path + os.sep + "GPX" + os.sep + filename) 


Am i doing something wrong? It works when using "Save As..." in QGIS though. So I guess it's not a driver version issue or something

Comment: I also tried 'lco FORCE_GPX_TRACK=YES', ['-lco FORCE_GPX_TRACK=YES'], ['lco FORCE_GPX_TRACK=YES'], ['FORCE_GPX_TRACK=YES']

Comment: I saw something:

Error: Wrong number of parameters
ALGORITHM: Convert format
 INPUT_LAYER <ParameterVector>
 DEST_FORMAT <ParameterSelection>
 DEST_DSCO <ParameterString>
 OUTPUT_LAYER <OutputVector>


DEST_FORMAT(Destination Format)
 0 - ESRI Shapefile
 1 - GeoJSON
 2 - GeoRSS
 3 - SQLite
 4 - GMT
 5 - MapInfo File
 6 - INTERLIS 1
 7 - INTERLIS 2
 8 - GML
 9 - Geoconcept
 10 - DXF
 11 - DGN
 12 - CSV
 13 - BNA
 14 - S57
 15 - KML
 16 - GPX
 17 - PGDump
 18 - GPSTrackMaker
 19 - ODS
 20 - XLSX
 21 - PDF

Comment: That makes me think that this algorithm only takes Datasource Creation Options (-dsco), and not Layer Creation Option (-lco)

Comment: See my extended answer.