# Automate conversion from SHP to GPX file with Python

Tags: python, shapefile, convert, gpx

I've been trying to establish a method whereby I can automatically convert a shapefile to a GPX file using python, but having terrible luck in doing so.

Currently the only method that i've come across is using ogr2ogr (GDAL library) and then parsing that through os.system.

```
os.system(('ogr2ogr -f GPX %s %s') % ((os.path.join(toDirectory,nameOfGPX +".gpx"), inputLineShpfile)))
```

Though the end goal is to get a product of how the DNR Garmin spits out a GPX (see below).

As you see below it doesn't look good with multipart polygons looking like a mess.

ogr2ogr using GDAL:
[image: Using ogr2ogr]

End goal (using a manual process of DNR Garmin to convert)

[image: Using DNR Garmin[2]]

Has anyone found a successful way to convert to gpx? I've got access to a basic version of ArcGIS and open to any open source or python libraries to assist.

Comment: A question asking for help writing code should include a snippet of the code you have tried, and details of what happens when you try it.  Please [edit] your question to include your code snippet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using 'ogr2ogr' algorithm in QGIS to transform SHP to GPX](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200762/using-ogr2ogr-algorithm-in-qgis-to-transform-shp-to-gpx)