# How to convert UTM to gpx in QGIS

Tags: qgis, utm, gpx

I have a problem to convert UTM datasets in to a .gpx file.
The dataset (800 sets) is like this:`Name Number (Zone East North for UTM)`
`Adam-Riese-Strasse 40 (32U 5550307,25 475061, 14)`.
After importing from text file, I would like to convert the Layer, the problem is that I must select a field that contains MGRS coordinates. But I have 3 fields with coordinates.
I have no idea how to continue. File:
Name Number Zone East North
Adam-Riese-Strasse 36 32U 5550231,21 474947,80
Adam-Riese-Strasse 37 32U 5550232,80 474949,70
Adam-Riese-Strasse 38 32U 5550290,58 475033,05
Adam-Riese-Strasse 39 32U 5550298,99 475047,33
Adam-Riese-Strasse 40 32U 5550307,25 475061,14

http://up.picr.de/32303039ss.jpg
I believe in the import I'm still doing something wrong. my layer has a different icon than yours. It looks like a word document icon in front of the name. in your picture it is a dot in front of the name I do not get anything in the map

Comment: You only need the "East" and the "Nord". What is the delimiter? For better help, you should upload the text **file**.

Comment: how do I upload the file?

Comment: the original is .xls. I exported it as a text file. I can choose the separator myself. Here I chose the blank

Comment: Ok that looks better. Where is your specific problem now? Space is a bad Separator.

Answer (score 2):

```
Name;Number;Zone;North;East
Adam-Riese-Strasse;36;32U;5550231,21;474947,80
Adam-Riese-Strasse;37;32U;5550232,80;474949,70
Adam-Riese-Strasse;38;32U;5550290,58;475033,05
Adam-Riese-Strasse;39;32U;5550298,99;475047,33
Adam-Riese-Strasse;40;32U;5550307,25;475061,14
```

**1) Import csv with EPSG: 25832**
[image]

Choose EPSG:25832 for 32U

[image]

Note: North and East are reversed.

**2) Export gpx with EPSG: 4326**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Right Click -> Layer Save as -> Format GPX

Comment: I believe in the import I'm still doing something wrong.
my layer has a different icon than yours. It looks like a word document icon in front of the name. in your picture it is a dot in front of the name
I do not get anything in the map

Comment: if I want to convert the file I use the extension: Lat Log Tools.
I go to MGRS to Geometry. I only have 1 Field for Coordinates to choose from.
How did you do the transformation?

Comment: I do not understand **why you need the LatLonTools**?
1) Import csv with EPSG: 25832
2) Export gpx with EPSG: 4326

Comment: I've pasted a link to a picture. As you can see, I do the import just like you.
But I do not create a dot file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (in QGIS 3.0) you must detect "Dezimaltrenner ist ein Komma"

Comment: You must set "Decimal separaator is comma". 

QGis 2.x has truncated the fields in the case. For QGIS 3.0, it leads to the behavior you described.

Comment: so far so good but exporting is not possible. Here is the picture of my settings  http://up.picr.de/32303548hp.jpg

Comment: Why "is not possible"? Errormessage? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40731/converting-shp-into-gpx-using-qgis/40733

Comment: OGR-Fehler: Failed to create GPX file test.gpx.

Comment: Is this the complete error message? Look here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40731/converting-shp-into-gpx-using-qgis/40733

Comment: this is the complete error message:
Generation of the data source failed (OGR-Fehler: Failed to create GPX file test.gpx).

Comment: .I go the way over save as. and then as can be seen in the picture.
I have already tried several things but apparently he can not create a file

Comment: Did you test the suggested solutions in the link? I have updated the image "save as" for QGIS 3.0.

Comment: I could create a gpx file.
if I understand the information from the link correctly, you always lose the ID (name_Info) of the individual points.
That's a problem. Which of the possibilities do you see for the naming?

Comment: I want to thank you. You helped me a lot.
I found a way, with the detour via .kml.
Thank you very much Mike 2