# Export Vector Layer into Multiple GPX Files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, vector, splitting

I have a vector layer that contains multiple attributes that I want to export as individual GPX files.  In this instance, the "Save Features As" option exports all of these attributes as 1 GPX file that includes all the attributes.  However, I need multiple gpx files that contain one attribute per file.

I try to use the Split Vector Layer tool/script but when I export to GPX (using the bulk processing) I get the result that the split failed because I need to turn on the GPX extensions.

Error Message: Creation of field id failed(OGR error: Field of name 'id' is not supported in GPX schema.  Use GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS creation option to allow us of the  element.)

How can I turn on the ability to use GPX extensions when using this script?

Image below for reference.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].  Please [Edit] the question to contain the error message as text -- images may not be legible on all devices, and their text can't be searched by others looking to find this Question.

Comment: Split Vector Layer only saving geopackage > https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29522

Comment: You might get some ideas here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40731/converting-shp-into-gpx-using-qgis?rq=1.

Answer (score 0):

I would go the alternative way using GDAL to do some scripting. Be aware I'm using bash because working on a Linux machine. I suppose you can do something similar on Windows machine with enough Powershell knowledge (to remove first line in CSV, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074271/remove-top-line-of-text-file-with-powershell)

```bsh
# Get unique list to CSV file
ogr2ogr -f CSV out.csv input.shp -sql "SELECT unique_colum FROM input"
# tail is to remove header first line
# Then, we loop other each unique_column value to generate each GPX file
for i in $(tail -n +2 out.csv);
  do ogr2ogr -f GPX  -dsco GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=YES "output_"$i".gpx" -sql "SELECT * FROM input WHERE unique_colum = '"$i"'";
done;
```